AdManagerBannerAd requesting multiple sizes, but not returning size for the ad, flutter google ad manager
i am using google_mobile_ads: ^5.2.0 to display adds on my flutter app.
I need to request and display 3 different sizes of banner ads from google.
This ad is supposed to be show in a scrollable column so i must set the height of it, the problem is that when the add is loaded i don't have the information about the loaded ad, it could be any of the three.
If i don't set the height it is either hidden or there is an error that the height cannot be infinite.
note: in the snippet in only set the temporary size, because i don't know how to get the correct one.
 Future<void> loadAd() async {
    _bannerAd = AdManagerBannerAd(
        adUnitId: adUnitId,
        request: const AdManagerAdRequest(),
        sizes: [
          const AdSize(width: 300, height: 100),
          const AdSize(width: 300, height: 250),
          const AdSize(width: 300, height: 600)
        ],
        listener: AdManagerBannerAdListener(
          onAdLoaded: (ad) {
            if (!mounted) {
              ad.dispose();
              return;
            }
            debugPrint('$ad loaded.');
            setState(() {
              _isLoaded = true;
            });
          },
          onAdFailedToLoad: (ad, error) {
            debugPrint('AdManagerBannerAd failed to load: $error');
            ad.dispose();
          },
        ))
      ..load();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    
    _bannerAd?.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return _isLoaded && _bannerAd != null
        ? Align(
            alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
            child: SafeArea(
              child: SizedBox(
                width: _bannerAd!.sizes[0].width.toDouble(),
                height: _bannerAd!.sizes[0].height.toDouble(),
                child: AdWidget(ad: _bannerAd!),
              ),
            ),
          )
        : const SizedBox
            .shrink(); 
  }

please help.
